# inserting data into SQL cell, My SQL DB

Tags: python, mysql

I have created MYSQL DB using XAMPP and created table using python

```
self.sql = """CREATE TABLE Report_SV (
                 Date  VARCHAR(160) ,
                 StartTime  VARCHAR(160),
                 EndTime  VARCHAR(160),
                 SystemName VARCHAR(160),
                 TestBench VARCHAR(160),
                 DomainName VARCHAR(100),
                 SourceFile CHAR(200),
                 Build_Info VARCHAR(200),
                 HLF VARCHAR(200),
                 TestcaseID VARCHAR(60),
                 TestCaseName VARCHAR(100),
                 Test_Step TEXT(1000),
                 Step_Result VARCHAR(500))"""
```

While inserting data into one of its cell my data is not shown properly and only truncated data is viewed.

[image]

```
sql = "INSERT INTO report_sv (Test_Step) VALUES ('FES.statusFESVehicleDynamicSwitchHMI.requestSwitchDrivingExperienceMMIDisplay=1')";
```

I don't know what is the proper way to insert complete data?

Comment: Surely that's just whatever tool you are using to view the database truncating for readability?

Comment: No, i don't think so. i tried expanding and even copying pasting but the data is shown is FES.statusFESVehicleDynamicSwitchHMI.requestSwitch... only